# What is the purpose of calling fcntl() be called with the file descriptor as -1 and cmd as F_GETFL?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, freebsd, fcntl

I am trying to understand what this line of code means:

```
flags = fcntl(-1,F_GETFL,0);
```

Answer (score 4):

The usual reason for calling [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with the `F_GETFL` flag is to modify the flags and set them with `fcntl()` and `F_SETFL`; the alternative reason for calling `fcntl()` with `F_GETFL` is to find out the characteristics of the file descriptor.  You can find the information about which flags can be manipulated by reading (rather carefully) the information about [`<fcntl.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/fcntl.h.html).  The flags include:

- O_APPEND — Set append mode.
- O_DSYNC — Write according to synchronized I/O data integrity completion.
- O_NONBLOCK — Non-blocking mode.
- O_RSYNC — Synchronized read I/O operations.
- O_SYNC — Write according to synchronized I/O file integrity completion.

Plus (POSIX 2008) O_ACCMODE which can then be used to distinguish `O_RDONLY`, `O_RDWR`, and `O_WRONLY`, if I'm reading the referenced pages correctly.

However, it makes no sense whatsoever to call `fcntl()` with a definitively invalid file descriptor such as `-1`.  All that happens is that the function returns `-1` indicating failure and sets `errno` to `EBADF` (bad file descriptor).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming we are talking about the function described by `man 2 fcntl`:

```
flags = fcntl(-1,F_GETFL,0);
```

tries to perform some action on an invalid file descriptor (`-1`) and therefore will **never do anything else** but returning `-1` and set `errno` to `EBADF`.

I'd say you can savely replace this line by:

```
flags = -1; errno = EBADF;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`fcntl()`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/apis/fcntl.htm) function performs various actions on open descriptors. Its syntax is:

```
int fcntl(int descriptor,
          int command,
          ...)
```

read about **Return Value**:

- `-1` then  `fcntl()` was not successful. The errno global variable is set to indicate the error.

this code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main(){
   int flags;   
   if((flags = fcntl(-1,F_GETFL,0)) < 0){
    perror("fcntl: ");
   }
   printf("\n %d\n", flags);
}
```

output is:

```
~$ gcc xx.c
~$ ./a.out 
fcntl: : Bad file descriptor

 -1
```

Notice the printed   `flags` value is `-1` that indicates not successful call of `fcntl(-1,F_GETFL,0);`  because `-1` is not a valid file descriptor. And [valid file descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) starts from `0`. (that is what [`perror()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/perror/) prints error message  [Bad file descriptor](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-errnovariable/), EBADF)

**note:** I run this code in Linux System.

**Edit**:
`F_GETFL` is for GET flags command in fcntl().

Comment: So the purpose of your code is nothing but shows that `-1` is not a valid file descriptor :) , let me know if you need more help on this.